# Не могу создать уведомление

Tags: android, android-notification

Не могу создать уведомление в Android Studio и ошибок никаких не выдает

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent intent;
//    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(getApplicationContext(), 0, MainActivity);
    public static String testOrTraining = "";
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "Word channel";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void onClickBt(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.words_training:
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, CHANNEL_ID)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                                .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
                                .setContentText("Пора покормить кота")
                                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

                NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                        NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this);
                notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());

                intent = new Intent(this, worldTraining.class);
                worldTraining.countRight = 0;
                worldTraining.countFalse = 0;
                testOrTraining = "training";
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.test:
                intent = new Intent(this, activityTest.class);
                activityTest.countRight = 0;
                activityTest.countFalse = 0;
                testOrTraining = "test";
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.changelanguage:
                intent = new Intent(this, SetLanguage.class);
                SetLanguage.language = "";
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: попробуйте в CHANNEL_ID убрать пробелы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, CHANNEL_ID) не создает канал под идом CHANNEL_ID, он публикует в канал CHANNEL_ID, если он уже есть. 
Нужно создавать каналы вручную:

```
private static final String CHANEL_ID = "word_channel";
private static final String CHANEL_NAME = "Word channel";

private void createChannels() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        return;

    //1) id 2) имя канала 3) приоритет
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANEL_ID, CHANEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

Вызывайте данный метод перед показам уведомления.

Comment: Большое спасибо, это сработало только нужно было еще в build.grandle добавить эту строку ```implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'```

Comment: @Neirt, странно, по идее эта библиотека должна и так подключаться во все проекты в Android Studio, т.к. это по сути системная библиотека.